# Study if $f$ is continuous or differentiable, depending on the values ​​of $n$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function defined by

$$ f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \dfrac{x^ny}{x^6+y^2} &\text{if} \ \ \ \  \ \ (x,y) \neq(0,0), \\[10pt] 0 &\text{if} \ \ \  \ \ \ \  x=0=y.  \end{cases} $$

Study if $f$  is continuous or differentiable, depending on the values ​​of $n$.

Comment: To get started, you can easily see that $|f(x,y)|\leq |y|$ when $n\geq 6$. Then for $n\leq 4$, consider $f(x,x)$ to prove discontinuity. It remains to treat $n=5$ for continuity/discontinuity.

Comment: And for $n=5$, consider $f(x,\sqrt{x})$ to prove discontinuity.